# i thought i was able to vote to close questions?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

there's a question from a new person with rep=1 that is simply a photo of a page from a textbook.  as two close votes already, but it says it needs 3 more.  but there doesn't appear to be a way for me to cast a close vote on it.  and it does not appear in the "Close votes" category in my "review" menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some nearly concurrent events happened. The question was closed by a moderator at 2016-04-17 01:07:39Z. Your post here on meta was created at 2016-04-17 01:12:56Z. So, I suppose the following happened:

1. You opened the question page, which had two close votes at the time
2. A moment later, a moderator closed the question.
3. Your close vote would not be accepted since the server knew the question was closed, although the page loaded in your browser did not show it.

Suggestion: when Stack Exchange posts behave in a strange way, reload the page.

Comment: That seems like a good analysis of what happened.  I've been caught like that too, so it certainly sounds like a reasonable explanation.